# My HTML table has double numbers

Tags: html, grails

I am working on a grails project and have two sortable **th** in my code but its producing 4 **th** in which two are an empty **th**. i dont know why this is happening and have to add two mote **td** in my table to get them in the same row.here is my code

`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th> <g:sortableColumn  property="planYear" title="first th"/> </th>
    <th> <g:sortableColumn  property="createdby" title="second th"/> </th>
   </thead>
</table>
```

`
so can some one tell me why this is happening and how to deal with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<g:sortableColumn/>` is the cell. It should not be wrapped within an additional `<th />`. You should, however, wrap them in a `<tr />`.